# FTP connection refused to anonymous server

Tags: ftp

I am trying to connect to a public FTP server that allows anonymous connexions. The server is fr2.rpmfind.net and it works from my terminal

```
ftp fr2.rpmfind.net
Connected to mandril.creatis.insa-lyon.fr.
```

Now I have another terminal with SSH to a remote machine and for the same command this is what I get:

```
ftp: connect: Connection refused
```

How can I get a connection refused if FTP server allows anonymous connexions?

Comment: The second host could be filtering FTP.  Can you connect to any other FTP service from that host?

Comment: Are you trying to connect using SSH from the SSH terminal?

Comment: i'm trying to connect using ftp just entering ftp fr2.rmpfind.net

Comment: @Aaron I've tried with ftp.mozilla.org and got the same Connection refused message

Comment: Gotcha. Could it be that the FTP server is blocking connections from the ip address of the SSH terminal?

Comment: @joeqwerty let me try call the ftp server from another remote host I have
result: yes i can connect using a different remote host as the ftp client

Comment: Like Aaron said, the machine you're connecting via SSH to, seems to either:

Comment: so what should I do? Is this something I can fix on my side or this is on the FTP serevr's side and there's really nothing i can do about this?

Comment: Like Aaron said, the machine to which you're connected via SSH seems to block outgoing FTP connections, or higher ports for active/passive FTP connections. Do you have root access at the destination machine? If so, you could check the local iptables rules: iptables -L -vn

Comment: Since you tested two FTP sites without success it definitely sounds like FTP is filtered for that second host.  Your next step depends on if you administer that host or the network.  The filtering could be occuring at either point.  Check iptables to see if it's filtered locally. (service iptables status)  If not, it's got to be at the network level.

Comment: I'm thinking PASV is unlikely.  Before the handoff to PASV the connection would succeed and he'd see that before PASV fails.  Also, using a low level command line FTP utility is likely not forcing PASV.  Can you try a -v or -V flag to get more information?

Comment: FTP connection refused is generated by the FTP server. I've never seen it generated on the client.

Comment: @joeqwerty: 'ftp: connect: Connection refused' surely can show up on the client side (Linux). 'Connection refused' appears if either the source or the destination machine got FTP blocking rules (REJECT) in their iptables. DROP rules lead to 'Connection timeouts' instead. Edit: PS: Verified this a few minutes ago on 2 Linux machines (hostA calls 'ftp hostB', while hostB is blocking TCP20/21 in reject style) = connection refused msg on hostA.

Comment: @faboja: Besides the question if there is a firewall running on the host you're connected to via SSH: Is that particular 2nd host located in a corp/gov/edu network? If so, the outbound firewall of the network could also be the blocking bit.

Comment: @desasteralex: Thanks for the insight. I've never seen the connection refused generated by the client. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Try running a traceroute to the server from both site, checking to see if a router is blocking your connection at some point along the route.